# Deleting a button from viewController from its subclass code?

Tags: ios, swift

I've basically got some code where I'm moving buttons around on my screen and if the button is dropped onto a certain view, I need for that button to get removed from the view.

I thought self.removeFromSuperview() would maybe work because I figured it might base what the superView is based on what view the button is at the time of that code firing off? but I guess I don't exactly understand all that.

Is there a way to make this work within my touchesEnded func where I'm checking to see if the button was dropped in the view or do I need to send a NSNotification to my other view and handle it there?

I've just got something printing out atm and it works, the deletion just isn't happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `removeFromSuperview` on the button pointer.

`myButton.removeFromSuperview()`

Also, make sure you're calling `removeFromSuperview` on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you have UIButtons on the screen, and the user can drag them.  If they drag them to a certain spot (let's call this the trash bin), you want to remove it.

You certainly don't want to remove your own view controller from the superview, which is what self.removeFromSuperView() is doing.  Instead, in touchesEnded, try this:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)

    let touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch

    if touch.view.isKindOfClass(UIButton) {
        touch.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }


}
```